# papaparse not reading row during step if there's a delay in the function

Tags: javascript, papaparse

So, my code looks like this:

```
        Papa.parse(my_local_file, {
            step: async function(row, parser){
                console.log('starting wait');
                await new Promise(res => {setTimeout(() => {res(7)}, 10000)});
                console.log('Row -> ' + row.data);
            },
            complete: function (){
                console.log('complete');
            }
        });
```

lets say the file has 10 rows in it, it will print 10 `starting wait` without any delay between them and then immediately after that, it will print `complete`. and then 10 secs after that, it will print the rows. I was expecting there's a delay of 10 secs for each row. the 10 sec delay is only once, and all the rows will print immediately. it's as if the `step` function is run concurrently?

What's going on here?

EDIT: fixed the code

Comment: hey! did you find any solution for your issue?